# Python Regex pattern matching with a variable name not working

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

The below code does not return True for the match. I am wondering why? Any help is appreciated.

Note:
id_list = ['YYY-100', 'YYYMM1640ASS20', 'Cruzer', 'SSDSC2BA20', 'BBBPEDMD40']

'drives.txt' contains lines like this (and does contain above IDs in some lines).

'RED SSDSC2BA200G4R     200 GB     2.5     SATA     6G     Class E: 30,000-100,000 writes per second'

So I would assume that id 'SSDSC2BA20' will match the second word in above line, but below match does not return True. 
For double-checking, I tried 'if match: print match.group()' but that returns nothing as well. What am I missing?

---

```
import re

with open('drives.txt', 'r') as fr:
  for id in id_list:
    for line in fr:
      match = re.search(r'%s' % id, line, re.I)
      if match:
        print 'True'
```

---

Note that instead of above regex, I tried the below also, but that did not work either.
  my_regex = r".?" + re.escape(id) + r".?"
  match = re.search(my_regex, line, re.I)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fr` is a file pointer. With your current approach, you're iterating over the lines multiple times, once for each regex. Don't do this. Everytime you read a line, you advance the file pointer till it points to the end of the file. This happens on the first iteration itself, so forthcoming iterations will have you read empty strings from the file.

One fix for this is to do `fr.seek(0, 0)` after each inner loop, which I don't recommend. The other fix is to reorder your loops. Iterate over your file once. Here's how you do that:

```
with open('drives.txt', 'r') as fr:
    for line in fr:
        for id in id_list:
            match = re.search(r'%s' % id, line, re.I)
            if match:
                print id, 'matches for line:', line
```

Also, I should mention that using `id` as a variable name shadows the builtin `id()` function, so I recommend you change it.